# Lightning component, controller function with multiple parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller

Here is my component:

```
<aura:attribute name="showA" type="String" default="admin" /> 
<aura:attribute name="showB" type="String" default="help" /> 


<a href="#" data-show="{!v.showP}" onclick="{!c.show}" id="New">Link1<a/>
<a href="#" data-showQ="{!v.showQ}" onclick="{!c.show}"  id="Sent">Link2<a/>
```

Now, whenever a user will click I will get the value of op and op2, but what I want is to use a single attribute and change the value according to the link.

```
show: function(component,event,helper) {

    var op = event.currentTarget.dataset.show;

    var op2 = event.currentTarget.dataset.showQ; 

    alert(conole.log(op +':::::::::'+ op2));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is one way of using a single attribute and setting values for it

Component:

```
 <aura:attribute name="show" type="String" default="help" /> 
  <a href="#" data-show="{!v.showP}" onclick="{!c.show}" id="New">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-showQ="{!v.showQ}" onclick="{!c.show}"  id="Sent">Link2</a>
```

Controller:

```
show:function(component,event,helper) {
    var op = event.currentTarget.id;
    if(op === 'New') 
    component.set('v.show', 'A');
     if(op === 'Sent')
    component.set('v.show', 'B');
    alert(console.log( component.get('v.show')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you dont need two data-set reference I mean <s>`data-show="{!v.showP}"`</s>  
and <s>`data-showQ="{!v.showQ}"`</s> 
simply you can refer `data-show` on both link  `data-show="{!v.showP}"` and `data-show="{!v.showQ}"`

**In controller** 
 you dont need to get it from  `op and op2` variable. If you want to set to single attribute regarding the value getting according to the link simply In your markup include  `<aura:attribute name="show" type="String" />`

```
({
    show : function(component, event, helper) {
        var op = event.currentTarget.dataset.show;
        component.set('v.show',op);//set here the value according to the link clicked
    }
})
```